# Make field read-only based on whether form is valid Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to make one field readonly only if form is valid (after submitting data).
I tried to override `get_readonly_fields` in admin but I have no access to form.

I have order form.
Once status of order is changed to 'Completed', I want to show all fields as readonly (admin can't edit form).
If I enter invalid data and change status to 'Completed', then all fields become readonly, but error is shown and data is not updated.
I want to avoid it. I want to make fields readonly, only if form is valid and status is set to 'Completed'.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean. Once the form is valid, you normally don't show it any more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a field read-only, but only when editing objects. You can indeed use the `get_readonly_fields` hook for that, because you get the current object as param `obj`: `get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None)`. So `if obj is None`, you are adding an object, otherwise, you are editing. For example:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self.readonly_fields
        else:
            return ["your_special_field"] + self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: This will work for all forms. I need to make field read-only onli if form is valid.

Comment: But if the form is valid, the user won't even see it, right? Because the admin will save and redirect afterwards...

Comment: Admin can open it and see details of submitted data. See my updated post.